# What is the equivalent for "service servicename start" that Fedora/RHEL/CentOS uses for Debian/Ubuntu?

Tags: linux, debian, fedora, service, redhat

What is the equivalent for "service servicename start" that Fedora/RHEL/CentOS uses for Debian/Ubuntu?
I've just read on some question here on serverfoault that using /etc/init.d/service is obsolete, so what's the correct way on Debian?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I don't know about the "correct" way, but I always use `invoke-rc.d`, so e.g. to restart MySQL:

```
sudo invoke-rc.d mysql restart
```

Answer (score 8):

You can always just invoke the startup scripts directly (e.g., /etc/init.d/foo restart).  This works on RedHat variants as well, although the path is slightly different there (/etc/rc.d/init.d, although I believe /etc/init.d is a symlink to it as well).

Comment: I use /etc/init.d foo stop|start|restart as well.

Comment: Cribbing from a comment on another question (http://serverfault.com/questions/30701/how-to-enable-sshd-on-fedora-11), directly calling /etc/init.d/servicename is discouraged on Fedora/Red Hat systems.  You also don't necessarily get the same environment provided to the scripts as you would using the /sbin/service script (e.g. on SELinux Gentoo you need to use `run_init` instead of /etc/init.d to get things to start in the correct security context.

Answer (score 5):

all most every distro has /etc/init.d/service ********** {start|restart|reload|stop}

Answer (score 4):

The same `service <servicename> start` works for me in Ubuntu 9.04. It is in the sysvinit-utils package.

Answer (score 3):

Using /etc/init.d/foo on RedHat can cause problem if selinux is activated because the script should not set up the context correctly. The service command always works on selinux enabled RHEL.

Answer (score 2):

I suggest that you read about Upstart:

http://upstart.ubuntu.com/

http://www.linux.com/archive/feature/125977

http://www.netsplit.com/category/tech/upstart/

It is used on:

- Ubuntu 6.10 and later
- Fedora 9 and later
- Debian (as an option)
- Nokia's Maemo platform
- Palm's WebOS

Answer (score 1):

Yep, that's what I use too. /usr/sbin/invoke-rc.d is the way to go.

Answer (score 1):

Whatever about on Redhat systems, /etc/init.d/service is still the norm on debian derivatives.